# How do I add Xinput to a gamepad arduino project?

Tags: arduino, driver, gamepad

I have successfully running push buttons and analog sticks working on a board of mine through the serial connection via the Arduino IDE. How do I get that data to work with Xinput?

I have my own emulation software that works in Xinput beyond that. I just need to get the gamepad device xinput support.  What are the neccessary steps to get this working with a driver and how I can get this up in running in the least amount of timing possible without having to edit someone else's driver too much?

Comment: Switch to a device that supports USB natively, and write HID firmware.

Comment: It's going to be operable via my USB port on my Arduino. How do I go about finding Xinput HID firmware?

Answer (score 0):

You can [turning an Arduino Leonardo into a joystick](http://www.imaginaryindustries.com/blog/?p=80), use a [teensy board](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/index.html) and the [teensy joystick library](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_joystick.html), use a HID-compatible bluetooth chip (such as [RN-42 HID](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10938) or something similar) with a joystick/gamepad profile or just remove a controller's existing joystick parts and replace with your components.

Comment: I am interested specifically in Xinput. reading the articles this does not seem to be the case.

Comment: You can realize a regular joystick (as described above) and implement a DirectInput application or if you need really Xbox 360 Controller use a [Xbox 360 Controller Emulator](https://github.com/x360ce/x360ce) to transfer your regular joystick.

Comment: Let's say I am a device manufacturer and need Xinput support on my gamepad to make this work on all xinput supported games on Windows. I develop emulation software for Xinput already. Think from a device manufacturer perspective.

Comment: Is there a driver I can download?